# How to retrieve only a list of the eager loaded elements in laravel 5?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

In my case, I have a user, who has many posts that each have comments and my goal is to retrieve only a collection of comments through the use of eloquent relationships (without creating a custom collection and looping, if possible).

Current I have this:

```
$comments = $user->posts()->with('comments')->get();
```

This returns a collection of posts with related comments in each of them, however I wish just a collection of comments.

I hope this makes sense - thanks!

Comment: So you want all user comments or all post comments?

Comment: all comments on posts that belong to the user

Comment: then you should have in comments table also user_id, and you can relate to comment from user directly

Comment: well, the user_id in the comments table is of the user who made the comment

Comment: I finaly get, what you want, if im not wrong. It should be someting like this: `\App\Models\Comment::with(['post' => function ($query) use ($user) {$query->where('user_id', $user->id);}])->get();`